# useState isn't working when parent useState function is applied

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, event-handling, state

I have a ticket child class that sets the total amount after no of tickets has been been changed the problem i am facing here is setNumber doesn't seem to work unless setTotal is commented out, i don't understand this and could use some help regarding this issue

```js
const Booking = () => {

    let [total, setTotal] = useState(0)

    const Ticket = ({ ticket, index }: any) => {

        let [number, setNumber] = useState(0);

        const handleChange = (e: any) => {

            const order = {
                eventid: eventid,
                amt: ticket.price * e.target.value,
                type: ticket.type,
                tickets: e.target.value,
                email: userdata!.email,
                ticketid: ticket.ticketid,
            }

            orders[index] = order

            //setNumber doesn't seem to work unless setTotal is commented out
            setNumber(Number(e.target.value))
            console.log(number)

            let sum = orders.reduce((accumulator: number, object: any) => {
                return accumulator + object.amt;
            }, 0)
            setTotal(sum)

        }
         return (
            <div className="p-5 space-y-5 grid grid-cols-6">

                    <select name="number" onChange={handleChange} value={number}>
                        <option value={0}>0</option>
                        <option value={1}>1</option>
                        <option value={2}>2</option>
                        <option value={3}>3</option>
                        <option value={4}>4</option>
                        <option value={5}>5</option>
                        <option value={6}>6</option>
                        <option value={7}>7</option>
                        <option value={8}>8</option>
                        <option value={9}>9</option>
                        <option value={10}>10</option>

                    </select>
                </div>

        )
}
```

I've tried changing adding the setTotal function as a parameter to the child component but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

In you case you may try using `useEffect`. Because of the asynchronous nature  `useStrict`, When you call setNumber(Number(e.target.value)), it will not update the state. The console.log(number) immediately after setNumber will log the previous value of number, not the updated one. And when you comment out setTotal(sum), it seems to work because you are not relying on the updated value of `number` immediately afterward. But use `useEffect` like this:

```
const Ticket = ({ ticket, index }: any) => {
    let [number, setNumber] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(number);

        let sum = orders.reduce((accumulator: number, object: any) => {
            return accumulator + object.amt;
        }, 0);
        setTotal(sum);
    }, [number, setTotal, orders]); // Make sure to include dependencies

    const handleChange = (e: any) => {
        const updatedNumber = Number(e.target.value);

        const order = {
            eventid: eventid,
            amt: ticket.price * updatedNumber,
            type: ticket.type,
            tickets: updatedNumber,
            email: userdata!.email,
            ticketid: ticket.ticketid,
        }

        orders[index] = order;

        setNumber(updatedNumber);
    }

    // your component code

    return (
        // JSX for your component
    );
};
```

Comment: did try it, setNumber still doesn't seem to work, just for reference, let me show you the select tag as well where i am changing the value

Comment: Sorry, i think even the way i use `useEffect` seems to incorrect as it is being executed after the render, and as a result, the `setTotal` inside it might not be having the updated number state immediately, I have corrected it and if it doesn't work  have additional recommendation.

Comment: hey @Ermi it seems to work, i just had to place the child component in a different file